# How to convert JSON String to list<Class> and pass it as Wrapperlist on component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, json, wrapper-class

Hi am not able to get WrapperList working. I have tried this so far.

Here i want to pass the variable values of the response class - latestStatus into the Wrapper and display all the "history" values from the json String.

I have tried this so far. I think am missing something here. Please help.

Component: (only the relevant code added)

```
    <aura:attribute name="ApexController" type="FreightAWBPopUpController"/>

<aura:handler name="init" action="{!c.doInit}" value="{!this}" />
<aura:attribute name="BeforeAWB" type="Case"/>  

<center>
    <ui:button aura:id="button" buttonTitle="Opens a modal pop up" class="slds-button slds-button_brand" label="AWB Details" press="{!c.doAWB}"/>
</center>

<fieldset class="slds-form-element">
    <legend class="slds-form-element__label slds-text-title_caps">Latest Status history list</legend>

    <aura:iteration items="{!v.ApexController.historyList}" var="totalList">
        abcd2
        <p>{!totalList.LatestStatus.station}</p>
    </aura:iteration>
</fieldset>
```

Response Class:

```
public class Freight_AWBResponseParsing {

public class LatestStatus {
    public String station;
    public String milestone;
    public String creationdate;
    public String weight;
    public String pieces;
    public string flightDetails;
    public String unit;
}

public String xmlnssoapenv;
public ShipmentMilestones shipmentMilestones;


public class ShipmentMilestones {
    public ShipmentsTracked shipmentsTracked;
}

public class ShipmentsTracked {
    public String shipmentPrefix;
    public String masterDocumentNumber;
    public String origin;
    public String destination;
    public String consigneeName;
    public String shipperName;
    public String shipmentDescription;
    public String handlingCode;
    public String pieces;
    public String weight;
    public String weightUnit;
    public string units;
    public LatestStatus latestStatus;
    public List<LatestStatus> history;
}


public static Freight_AWBResponseParsing parse(String json) {
    return (Freight_AWBResponseParsing) System.JSON.deserialize(json, Freight_AWBResponseParsing.class);
}
```

}

Controller : (only the relevant code added)

```
global class FreightAWBPopUpController {

@AuraEnabled public Boolean isSuccess { get; set; }
@AuraEnabled public String msg { get; set; }
@AuraEnabled public Case controllerCase { get; set; }
@AuraEnabled public list<Freight_AWBResponseParsing.LatestStatus> historyList {get;set;}
@AuraEnabled public Freight_AWBResponseParsing.LatestStatus ls {get; set;}

@AuraEnabled
public static FreightAWBPopUpController getRecordUpdate(Id CaseId)
{

    FreightAWBPopUpController obj = new FreightAWBPopUpController();

    // Checking availability of AWB Number, accordingly requesting 
    if(String.isNotBlank(caseRecord.Freight_AWB_Number__c)){
        requestJson = getRequestString(username, password, caseRecord.Freight_AWB_Number__c);
    }
    else{
        // show error AWB Number not provided. Lightning work to be done
        obj.msg = 'AWB Freight Number cannot be null';
        obj.isSuccess = false;
        obj.controllerCase = caseRecord;
        return obj;
    }

    system.debug(' @@ j2Apex.sample string @@ ' + requestJson);
    // Http request parameter declaration
    string endPoint     = freightIcargoUserDetails.Endpoint__c;
    string method       = 'GET';

    // Http Request formation to be sent to iCargo system.
    HttpRequest req     = new HttpRequest();
    req.setEndpoint(endPoint);
    req.setMethod(method);
    req.setBody(requestJson);

    // Http Response requested from iCargo system.
    Http http           = new Http();
    HTTPResponse res    = http.send(req);

    System.debug('response VALUES' +res.getBody());

    try{

        Freight_AWBResponseParsing awbResponseParsed = Freight_AWBResponseParsing.parse(res.getBody());
        obj.historyList = awbResponseParsed.ShipmentMilestones.shipmentsTracked.history;
        obj.ls = awbResponseParsed.ShipmentMilestones.shipmentsTracked.latestStatus;

        system.debug(' @@ Latest Status @@ ' + obj.ls);
        system.debug(' @@ Latest Status List @@ ' + obj.historyList);            

        caseRecord = returnParsedCase(res.getBody(), caseRecord);
        caseRecord.Freight_AWB_Status__c = 'Infomation Recieved';
        update caseRecord;

        obj.isSuccess = true;
        obj.controllerCase = caseRecord;
        return obj;
    }
    catch (JSONException jsonExcep){
    }
}
```

}

js controller :

```
    ({
        doAWB : function(component, event, helper) {

            var action = component.get("c.getRecordUpdate");

            action.setParams({
                "CaseId" : component.get("v.recordId")
            });
            console.log("caseId :" + component.get("v.recordId"));

            action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
                var output = response.getReturnValue();
                console.log('output succ:'+output.isSuccess+'output msg'+output.msg);

                var state = response.getState();
                if(component.isValid() && state == "SUCCESS" && output.isSuccess){

                    // $A.get("e.force:closeQuickAction").fire();
                    component.set("v.isOpen", true);
                    component.set("v.ApexController", output);

                    $A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();
                } else if (state == "ERROR" || !output.isSuccess) {
                    var errors = response.getError();
                    if (errors[0] && errors[0].message) {
                        // Did not catch on the Server Side
                        component.set("v.message", errors[0].message);
                        component.set("v.messageError", true);
                        component.set("v.isOpen", false);
                    } else if ( !output.isSuccess ) {
                        // Did catch on the Server Side
                        component.set("v.message", output.msg);
                        component.set("v.messageError", true);
                        component.set("v.isOpen", false);
                    }
                }

            });
            $A.enqueueAction(action);
        },

        closeModal : function(component, event, helper) {
            component.set("v.isOpen", false);
            $A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();
        }
})
```

json String:

```
    {
  "@xmlns:soapenv": "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/",
  "shipmentMilestones": {
    "shipmentsTracked": {
      "shipmentPrefix": "111",
      "masterDocumentNumber": "11111",
      "origin": "sss",
      "destination": "SYDNEY",
      "consigneeName": "SYDNEY FISH MARKET",
      "shipperName": "sss",
      "shipmentDescription": "LIVE CRABS",
      "handlingCode": "AVP",
      "pieces": "4",
      "weight": "64.0",
      "weightUnit": "Kg",
      "units": null,
      "latestStatus": {
        "station": "SYD",
        "milestone": "Delivered",
        "shipmentdate": "25-Jun-2017 21:22:00",
        "weight": "64.0",
        "pieces": "4",
        "flightDetails": null
      },
      "history": [
        {
          "station": "SYD",
          "milestone": "Delivered",
          "shipmentdate": "25-Jun-2017 21:22:00",
          "weight": "64.0",
          "pieces": "4",
          "flightDetails": null
        },
        {
          "station": "SYD",
          "milestone": "Checked In",
          "shipmentdate": "25-Jun-2017 16:24:38",
          "weight": "7.0",
          "pieces": "1",
          "flightDetails": "QF0533, ARR ; SYD. 25-Jun-2017 15:37(A)"
        },
        {
          "station": "SYD",
          "milestone": "Checked In",
          "shipmentdate": "25-Jun-2017 16:24:38",
          "weight": "64.0",
          "pieces": "4",
          "flightDetails": "QF0533, ARR ; SYD. 25-Jun-2017 15:37(A)"
        },
        {
          "station": "GLT",
          "milestone": "Accepted",
          "shipmentdate": "25-Jun-2017 09:18:34",
          "weight": "64.0",
          "pieces": "4",
          "flightDetails": null
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Define "not able to get working". It will be much easier to help if you explain what's gong on

Comment: I need to pass the list<latestStatus> to the component and show every String variable in a table. Am trying to invoke that list by assigning it to list<Freight_AWBResponseParsing.LatestStatus> historyList {get;set;} and the value for the list comes from this obj.historyList = awbResponseParsed.ShipmentMilestones.shipmentsTracked.history; Now the problem is when i call the {v.ApexController.historyList} its not taking the values of the variable.